# Trigger to Re-parent

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 3 objects related by Master-Detail..
Monthly Activity (Parent) --> URL Monthly Activity (Child) --> URL Individual Activity (Grand Child).

The fields in Child and Grandchild get populated using integration.
What I am trying here is to re-parent Child to a different parent based on the values on grandchild.

My code is below. The trigger fires but it not re-parenting the records.

*** MODIFIED CODE ****

```
      trigger ReparentCreateRecords on URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c (before insert) {
    private ID urlMonId;
    private ID indMonId;
    private URL_Monthly_Activity__c urlMonAct;
    private URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c indMonAct;
    private Monthly_Activity__c currentMonthlyAct;
    private Monthly_Activity__c newMonthlyAct;

    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert){
        for(URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c IMA : (List<URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c>) Trigger.new){
            if((IMA.Submitted_Month__c <> Null) && (IMA.Month__c-IMA.Submitted_Month__c<=1) && (IMA.Action__c == 'Create')){
                indMonId = IMA.Id;
                urlMonId = IMA.URL_Monthly_Activity__c;
                **system.debug('***currentIndMonthlyAct***' + indMonId);**  // Returning Blank Value
                system.debug('***currentURLMonthlyAct***' + urlMonId);                      
            }        
   }
  }   
    indMonAct = [SELECT Id,GID__c, Name, URL_Monthly_Activity__c,Submitted_Month__c, Submitted_Year__c FROM URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c WHERE Id =: indMonId];
    system.debug('***GID__c***' + urlMonAct.GID__c);
    system.debug('***Submitted_Month__c***' + indMonAct.Submitted_Month__c);
    system.debug('***Submitted_Year__c***' + indMonAct.Submitted_Year__c);
    urlMonAct = [SELECT Id, Name, GID__c, Monthly_Activity__c FROM URL_Monthly_Activity__c Where Id =: urlMonId];
    system.debug('***urlMonAct***' + urlMonAct);
    system.debug('***GID__c***' + urlMonAct.GID__c);

    currentMonthlyAct= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Monthly_Activity__c Where Id =: urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c ];
    system.debug('***currentMonthlyAct***' + currentMonthlyAct); 
    newMonthlyAct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Monthly_Activity__c Where Month__c =:indMonAct.Submitted_Month__c AND Year__c =: indMonAct.Submitted_Year__c AND GID__c =: indMonAct.GID__c];
    system.debug('***newMonthlyAct***' + newMonthlyAct); 
    urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c = newMonthlyAct.Id;
    update urlMonAct;
    system.debug('***urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c***' + urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, you should never put a query nor a DML in a loop, for starters...

Comment: You can't possibly be entering your `if` block, otherwise you would get a run time exception on your second query.

Comment: Did you try debug logs to identify if any errors are thrown while re-parenting?

Comment: Okay I have modified the code to ensure DML and Query stay outside the loop.. How ever I am getting a blank value for the GrandChild record, although Apex is returning a value for the associate Child record... Huh.. interesting..

Comment: Hi login2ak. I've fixed your post for you. To format your code in the future, just highlight it and press Ctrl-K or Cmd-K, or click the `{}` button on the editor.

Comment: @sheesh .. Yes. Debug logs are the first place I was checking, but even with try-catch block, I couldn't locate an error in the original code. With this one how ever, I am getting a blank value for IMA.Id.. I think its because the trigger is Before Insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it worked ... Here is the final version.. I just need to test it during batch job .. I am hoping it should pass ... thanks everyone..

```
    trigger ReparentCreateRecords on URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c (after insert) {
        private ID urlMonId;
        private ID indMonId;
        private URL_Monthly_Activity__c urlMonAct;
        private URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c indMonAct;
        private Monthly_Activity__c currentMonthlyAct;
        private Monthly_Activity__c newMonthlyAct;

        if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
            for(URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c IMA : (List<URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c>) Trigger.new){
                if((IMA.Submitted_Month__c <> Null) && (IMA.Month__c-IMA.Submitted_Month__c<=1) && (IMA.Action__c == 'Create')){
                    indMonId = IMA.Id;
                    urlMonId = IMA.URL_Monthly_Activity__c;
                }        
       }
      }   
        indMonAct = [SELECT Id,GID__c, Name, URL_Monthly_Activity__c,Submitted_Month__c, Submitted_Year__c FROM URL_Individual_Monthly_Activity__c WHERE Id =: indMonId];
        urlMonAct = [SELECT Id, Name, GID__c, Monthly_Activity__c FROM URL_Monthly_Activity__c Where Id =: urlMonId];

        currentMonthlyAct= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Monthly_Activity__c Where Id =: urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c ];
        newMonthlyAct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Monthly_Activity__c Where Month__c =:indMonAct.Submitted_Month__c AND Year__c =: indMonAct.Submitted_Year__c AND GID__c =: indMonAct.GID__c];
        urlMonAct.Monthly_Activity__c = newMonthlyAct.Id;
        update urlMonAct;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments SOQL and DML needs to be moved out of the loop. additionally the 'limit 1' irritates me: if you are querying for child records at least the datamodel is 1:n so you should also receive a list of children.

To evaluate your specific scenario (which I can't) others might assist you more quickly if you could provide some testdata created by a few lines of apex and a brief expected vs. actual behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have modified the code to adhere to best practice and I think I know what might be the issue.